# Passports Thailand

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

My partner, who is Thai, has just become an Australian citizen. He is not supposed to hold both. We are going to Thailand. Should he travel on the Australian passport or should he use both passports? Would he leave and reenter on his Australian passport and enter and leave Thailand on his Thai passport? Would there be any problems at the Thai end?

Comment: My suggestion is better, as it is an intentionally generalized Q/A, rather than one worrying about particular intricacies of the UK/Saudi situation.

Comment: @CMaster should OP use the "dual citizenship okay" advice, or "not okay"?  Thailand's prohibition of dual nationality for its citizens elsewhere is apparently not enforced very strictly.

Comment: @jcaron the Thai attitude towards dual nationality is apparently somewhat different from the Saudi attitude.

Comment: @phoog No idea, seems op would be better placed to understand that one.

Answer (score 2):

If he has not formally renounced his Thai citizenship, then he is still Thai and should use his Thai passport to enter and exit Thailand.

He should use his Australian passport to exit and re-enter Australia.

I am not well versed in Australian citizenship law, but there is a reference on the government website that mentions a permanent resident of Australia could be come a dual citizen by becoming an Australian citizen, which to seems to me to mean your partner may be able retain his Thai citizenship - http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Citi/Curr/Dual-citizenship

Comment: You haven't mentioned Thai law.  In fact it appears somewhat complicated.  Thais who naturalize elsewhere are technically supposed to lose their Thai nationality, but in practice it seems that this rarely happens.

Comment: As you alluded to, Thais rarely lose their nationality as a result of accepting other citizenships.  All of my wife's friends (she is Thai) who have married, moved outside of Thailand and gotten citizenship in their new home countries stll maintain their Thai citizenship. tit